# How to add .plist file to all targets in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-analytics, sdk

Totally new to iOS but I'm currently trying to setup Google Analytics. I have followed [the SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift#add-config) and everything went great until this step:

> **Add the configuration file to your project**
>
> Drag the GoogleService-Info.plist file you just downloaded into the root of your Xcode project and add it to all targets.

It doesn't say anything on HOW to add it to all targets. Being new to Xcode and iOS in general, I'm completely lost. Anyone with an answer for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Select the GoogleService-Info.plist in the project navigator** (the file hierarchy on the left side of Xcode). Then, if it isn't open yet, **open the utilities bar** (click the top-right most button in Xcode). You will see a section '**Target Membership**'. Check all the checkboxes to add the .plist to all targets.

In most cases it is enough to just add the file to your project.

Comment: Is it possible that I don't see the "Target Memberships" section? I have Xcode 7 - Nevermind found it

Comment: For me the file didn't show up with drag and drop. I had to choose Add File from the menu before I could see it.

Comment: Using Xcode 8 - The `Target Membership` section didn't show up for me until I put the file in the correct folder, as a sibling of the original Info.plist. I originally put it on the top level next to all of my base level folders (e.g. Frameworks, Pods, etc.)

Comment: In my case checkbox for Target Membership for project name is disabled projetnameTest is active

Answer (score 19):

**Physically** drag the GoogleService-Info.plist file from your download folder ( or wherever you saved it) to your main project directory as shown below. Once you do that, the "Targets" dialog should open automatically and you can choose all targets (...click on all the targets shown)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In Xcode 6 
 Follow the step sequence in this digram.

1. First select your target.
2. Select build settings tab.
3. Search for "info.plist file"
4. Edit the value for key "info.plist file" (Add the actual plist path in step 4)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you select the plist in question and then go to the file inspector (press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or select the first tab on the right panel), you can select on which targets you wish to include it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update for Xcode 12.3:

It should be selected automatically, but check anyway:

ce you drag the file to the root dir, select it and on the very right hand side you will see Target membership, make sure all the targets are selected.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that GoogleService-Info.plist file should be added to xCode i.e. **open your xCode and drag the file to Runner > Runner**.

Then click on GoogleService-Info.plist. On the right side of he screen you can find Target Membership.